# Permission to delete locked pages, components etc?

Tags: 2013, 2013-sp1

Is there a non sys-admin permission I can assign to users that allows them to remove locks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without giving admin permission, it is not possible to undo checkout in order to delete pages, components.

The approach that we have used is, created GUI which has the functionality to undo checkout / delete pages, components etc. The GUI runs using one of the admin account.

Comment: Hi Hiren, Is this GUI Extension something you would like to share with the rest of the community ?

Comment: Unfortunately, since this part of client project I can't share the GUI extension however if you need any specifics or need any help then I will be more than happy to help.

Comment: Will keep that in mind, thx !