# How to grant undo-checkout / check-in to a user who isn't a system admin?

Tags: 2013, cme, permissions

Our client has requested that one of their user to be given the permission to undo check-in in components on their publication (09 and 05 level). Country specific country are created at the 05 level.

This user is a member of the "Publisher" group for a specific country (i.e. UK). The "Publisher" group is a member of the "Editor" group. The "Editor" group is assigned to the 05 publication (translation level).

The "Editor" group has the Folder Management, Component Management and Category Management for the publication level.

Things that I've tried:

- Add the Page Management and Structure Group Management permission on the Editor group.
- Read the "Rights and Permissions for Users and Groups" and "Rights to Content Manager Items" in SDL LiveContent documentation.
- Checked this link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300570/tridion-undo-checkout-check-in).

Is there a way for this user to check-in checked out components in the 05 level without making him a system administrator or creating a completely new group?

Thanks!

Comment: Similar question has already been asked. Please refer to question: > http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8363/permission-to-delete-locked-pages-components-etc/8365#8365

Comment: Technically the Page Management and Structure Group authorizations are _rights_ set in the Publication _for_ a given group. You've found the answer is already "not possible" (without workflow or an extension). A new group with different authorization still won't be able to check items in. Education and having users check in their items will help. But you can also give feedback to Product Management through the [Ideas site](http://ideas.sdltridion.com/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Undoing a check-out is a rather high impact action (discarding the edits made by someone else) that requires SysAdmin privileges.

Comment: I think the problem that the asker may be trying to solve is that items often don't get checked back in on Save and Close, or just Close. I see this happening all the time. People unintentionally leave the item checked out.  This happens so much, that going to an admin to check people's stuff back in is a big job.  The solution to this problem, IMO, is to ask people who check items out to do a bit more due diligence in checking them back in when done.

Comment: @NickoliRoussakov I've seen it happen a lot also, I don't think its actually the users fault, I think it mostly happens when the connection between the client (browser) and the server has high latency, and then the javascript which should handle the undo checkout when the window is closed, is called too late and silently fails (althoug it would be nice if the user fixes the mess their browser left behind ;o)

Answer (score 4):

As Rick notes, to undo a check-out you need to be an admin, and for very good reasons. I'll assume that you have taken this on board and if necessary explained it or otherwise revisited it with your stakeholders.

In the case of a checked-out component, you should generally have disciplines in place to ensure that people don't go on holiday leaving important things checked out. If that fails, it should be rarely, and for those rare occasions, it will be worth the trouble to copy the component, and use the copy instead. Most often, with a quick "where-used" it will turn out that you don't have much to fix up. (All this, of course, is supposing that you really can't manage to find a system administrator: most organisations have good emergency access to system administrators.)

It can still sometimes happen that you will want to make some admin functionality available to non-admins. What you need to do then is to write some software that performs the desired action, and have that run under an administrator account. Obviously, this is then your opportunity to enforce any necessary business rules. For example, you could have a service that offers a limited undo-checkout feature. You could integrate access to your service into the GUI with an extension.

Generally, the authorisation model in Tridion is well thought-out and is a good fit for what you should be doing with your system. Although it's technically possible to do what you're suggesting, I don't know of a single Tridion implementation where the "need" to do this has survived a careful analysis.

Comment: All fair but I've seen a lot of cases where when people just view a Component or Page (it is automatically checked out since there is no view functionality like there was in the R5 line anymore) and they close the browser, the undo checkout is not automatically performed (or it silently fails). So they are basically unaware that they have something checked out. That all being said, I do agree that   it makes a lot of sense that undo check-out is just an admin capability.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way for this user to check-in checked out components in the 05 level without making him a system administrator

Best possible way is to create a GUI extension to perform Undo Checkout which will be visible only to a specific group.

You can assign this new group to the client user. Hence only this user can perform this action and also you can track it by logging the user activities.

Comment: A GUI extension would only work in the context of some kind of privileged service like I described in my answer. Otherwise, you still have the problem that you need to be an admin to undo the checkout.

Comment: @DominicCronin: For GUI extension, by configuring a generic user account with admin access will perform undo checkout and also GUI extension should track the user who executed it (That is, actual user). Later stage if something goes wrong, we know who did this.